# Can OnionDuke malware actually spread to new systems through an image?

Tags: windows, apt

I do realize that questions about malware in images has been asked before. It just does not look like they answer the questions in this particular situation.

This is about the OnionDuke APT malware that F-Secure reported about [here](https://www.f-secure.com/weblog/archives/00002764.html) (note that this report is dated Friday, November 14, 2014).

My question is about information in [this article](https://www.f-secure.com/documents/996508/1030745/dukes_whitepaper.pdf) by F-Secure (according to which OnionDuke was found in 2014). This article says on p.23:

> In contrast however, for OnionDuke and MiniDuke the linked image files
>   contain embedded malware to be downloaded and executed, rather than
>   instructions.

And the information in [this recent article](https://newsfromthelab.files.wordpress.com/2015/11/cc-as-a-service.pdf) (also by F-Secure) which says the following:

[image: OnionDuke embedded in image]

Does this information about OnionDuke mean that it attempts to infect new systems by embedding itself inside an image that is executed when viewed by a user, or is that image for upgrading systems that are already infected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does this information about OnionDuke mean that it attempts to infect new systems by embedding itself inside an image that is executed when viewed by a user, or is that image for upgrading systems that are already infected?

From my understanding the payload needs to be extracted from the image by an existing instance of the malware or by a dropper. Other part of the report make this more clear in that they write ([The Dukes Whitepaper](https://www.f-secure.com/documents/996508/1030745/dukes_whitepaper.pdf), page 14):

> Screenshot of a tweet intended for
>   OnionDuke, with a link pointing
>   to an image file that embeds an
>   updated version of OnionDuke

Thus Twitter is part of the Command & Control structure and the malware will load the instructions from the tweet, i.e. where the update can be found. Embedding the malware inside the image is used to make it look innocent, so that firewalls or breach detection systems don't consider the data suspicious. And such an image can be easily placed on lots of trusted sites so that chances are high that the URL for the image will not be blacklisted.

The image itself is not used as an exploit vector, that is viewing the image inside the browser is harmless. It is only used as a container.